# Generating an audio file on the fly?

Tags: ios, audio

I need to generate on the fly an audio file for an alarm based app I'm working on. I need to include some bell sounds at certain intervals, and the length of the audio file depends on user input. Is there a way to do this? I'm thinking of using this approach to get around some of the background limitations on iOS, as you're allowed to play audio in the background. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if this will work around the iOS issues but do you really need audio *file* and not simply audio? Just something to think about for others to help answer.

Comment: You can use core audio APIs to generate your audio file, but I agree with @BjornRoche, it will be easier to just play the audio (bell sound) at the right time.

Comment: Playing sounds using a timer is probably not an option in his case, since the timer is paused when the app goes into background. That’s why he wants to assemble a longer audio track that would keep the app running in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily compose longer sounds from existing samples using AVFoundation, namely the `AVMutableComposition` class. But be vary that the background audio playback should make sense given your app’s purpose. Playing audio just to keep your app running in background will get your app rejected at the review.